# Modify RichHtmlField in SP2010 Master Page?

Tags: master-page, rich-text

I'd like to modify the RichHtmlField to disable the color controls in SharePoint 2010. I tried adding this to my master page:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" allowFontColorMenus="false" runat="server" />
```

but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the editing pages in SharePoint. Any ideas how to enable/disable controls in the rich HTML editor?

Comment: There is an option to disable buttons in Editor Toolbar. If you need technical help, please contact me on Anand.Thurubatla@gmail.com Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1):

You added a control to the masterpage, which does nothing to other RichHtmlFields, it's just it's own control. Are you using the SP2010 wiki style apges or publishing?

Comment: Ah, I see. So how do I modify the control on the page? I'm using the publishing pages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a new control to the masterpage you need to open up your Page Layout and modify the existing RichHtmlField controls.

They are under /_catalogs/masterpage/page_layout_file_name

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for a customer.
You can read a post in this url: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2012/03/how-to-modify-ribbon-of-richtextbox.html